# Relative URL in ASP:Hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a quick question for anyone who wants to answer, I've ran into a small problem where I need to make a website more SEO-friendly so we thought about having Subdirectories for 16 countries in 3 different languages. Let's say I have a menu in my footer which is a .master file with the following hyperlink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink14" runat="server" Text="Frequently asked questions" NavigateUrl="/faq/" SkinID="Footer" />
```

The problem here is: How can I specify a relative link in such a way that I only need 3 Masterpages just for the languages instead of 16 for each country of origin. So instead of hardcoding "~/uk/faq/" I want to make a link that will direct him to the specified country subfolder which he is in. I tried to do this with "../faq/" but to no avail.

Does anyone have an idea which I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user will always be in a url which starts with a 2 character country code you could set the NavigateUrl in the codebehind.

```
HyperLink14.NavigateUrl = string.Format("{0}/faq/", Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, 2));
```